# Unexpected End of File, not sure why

Tags: unexpectendoffile

I'm running into "Unexpected End of File" and I'm not sure why. I'm sure it's something simple but I haven't figured it out yet.
   Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code, Thank You.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.superjoe.practicecard.FullscreenActivity">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/goliath1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/imageGoliath"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello, I'm Goliath."
    android:textColor="#C62828"
    android:textSize="36dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/ImGoliath"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="12dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Don't be afraid, I don't bite..."
    android:textSize="26dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:textColor="#C62828"
    android:id="@+id/afraid"
    android:layout_below="@id/ImGoliath"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="18dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/unless"
    android:text="Unless!"
    android:textColor="#C62828"
    android:textSize="52dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/afraid"
    android:padding="24dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Youreacricket"
    android:text="YOU'RE A CRICKET!"
    android:textColor="#C62828"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textSize="42sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your FrameLayout tag under your RelativeLayout tag.

```
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had tried typing something similar but had it in the wrong place or typed wrong or something. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Can you mark my answer as the right one? Thanks!

Comment: That problem is solved but I can't get the app to run despite messing with it several times.  Learning process...

Comment: Yep. Don't give up. All those hours spent scratching your head will pay off one day.